# What is the base datastructure used in the STL stack in C++

Tags: c++, stl

What is the base data structure used to implement std::stack in C++ STL?

Comment: Google. By default deque, but changable. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Answer (score -2):

Stack is essentially an interface, the underlying type can be changed.

Comment: stack is a normal template class. A interface is something which cannot be instanciated because it has no method contents, that doesn´t apply for stack.

Comment: @deviantfan And that's why I said "basically". Stack provides a way to access data inside an actual container (normally deque), which is similar to what an interface would do.